# Laravel-Docker-Behat Localhost issue

Tags: laravel, curl, docker, localhost, yaml

I am trying to use Behat(for BDD) to get the content of the homepage. I just use the method from Behat\MinkExtension\Context\MinkContext

```
$this->visit();
```

but I still get page not found.
What is interesting is that I can actually

```
curl 127.0.0.1
```

and that works.
my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'

services:
  nginx:
    image: dydx/alpine-nginx-phpfpm
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./www:/var/www
      - ./sites:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled
    network_mode: "host"

  artisan:
    image: spiralout/dartisan
    volumes:
      - ./www:/var/www

  mysql:
    image: spiralout/alpine-mariadb
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./database:/var/lib/mysql

  composer:
    image: spiralout/dcomposer
    volumes:
      - ./www:/var/www

  nodejs:  
    image: spiralout/dnodejs
    volumes:
      - ./www:/var/www

  redis:
    image: spiralout/alpine-redis
    volumes:
      - ./redis-data:/data

volumes:
  www:
  sites:
  redis-data:
```

I then run

```
 docker exec -it <nginx_name> /bin/bash
```

and then try to run behat
Any help appreciated

Comment: try `$this->visit('/');`

Comment: Still "Page not found"

Comment: have you setup the route correctly?

Comment: I can see everything on http://localhost   
I tried   
        $this->iAmOnHomepage();
        $this->visit("http://localhost");
        $this->visit("http://localhost:80");
        $this->visit("http://localhost:8000");
        $this->visit("http://localhost:8888");
        $this->visit("http://127.0.0.1");
        $this->visit("/");
        $this->visit("/:80");
        $output = shell_exec('curl 127.0.0.1');
 last one works but is not helpful

Comment: What is interesting is that when I run 
php -S localhost:8888 -t public
It still doesnt work. So it doesnt have to do with Docker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this turned out to be to recreate the project including the dev-develop flag.
`composer create-project laravel/laravel new dev-develop`

Hope this saves time to someone